# How do you wrap var args in Go?

Tags: go

According to several groups posts, the following code should work:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func demo(format string, args ...interface{}) {
  var count = len(args)
  for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("! %s\n", args[i])
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", format)
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", args)
  fmt.Printf(format, args)
  fmt.Printf("\n")
}

func main() {
  demo("%s %d", "Hello World", 10)
  fmt.Printf("\n\n")
  demo("%d %s", 10, "Hello")
}
```

And yield "Hello World 10" and "10 Hello", but it does not. Instead it yields:

```
! Hello World
! %!s(int=10)
%s %d
[Hello World 10]
[Hello World %!s(int=10)] %d(MISSING)


! %!s(int=10)
! Hello
%d %s
[10 Hello]
[10 %!d(string=Hello)] %s(MISSING)
```

Which is to say that passing []interface{} to a function that takes ...interface{} as an argument *does not* expand the argument and instead simply passes it as the value. The first %s expands the []interface{} into a string, and no further arguments are processed.

I'm sure there must be lots of situations where this is required in logging; but I can't find any working examples of how to do it.

This is basically the 'vprintf' family of functions in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the OP program should "work". Maybe this was intended instead(?):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func demo(format string, args ...interface{}) {
        fmt.Printf(format, args...)
}

func main() {
        demo("%s %d\n\n", "Hello World", 10)
        demo("%d %s", 10, "Hello")
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/dBLl5rpRzH)

---

Output:

```
Hello World 10

10 Hello
```

Comment: ah, thank you. For the next person who can't find this, it's hidden here as a note in the spec: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters

Comment: @Doug, [this is also explained in "Effective Go"](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing) which seems to be a must-read for anyone new to the language.

Answer (score 4):

`fmt.Printf(format, args...)` should do what you want I think.